# Cannot connect 40" Samsung to 27" mac

Tags: macos, imac, display

I have got both an 27" iMac and a Samsung 40" TV in the same room for kids. They are only 10ft away from each other, and I'd like to get a mirror image of the iMac onto the TV.

I've seen this work in a computer shop but I'm unsure if it was a Samsung TV.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?  Your question doesn't really contain any useful information.  Are you using a displayport --> HDMI adapter (if not, then what)?  Does the Mac detect that another display has been connected?

Comment: If you're unsure of the type of your ports and connectors, post photos so others can help you.

Comment: based on an offline comment from Geoff - he is using a HDMI adapter, audio works, video works but the resolution is wonky.  So I think the real issue is "how can he adjust the resolution on an external display"

Comment: The resolutions won't be the same, so wouldn't one of the displays have to run at a lower resolution resulting in the poorer quality? If you use it as a second display, you'd be able to set the native resolution for each display and drag the applications you want to use onto the relevant one.